# If one is using a *.cls that requires a graphic file, where should the auxiliary files be so that it works?

Tags: document-classes, auxiliary-files, texmf

I am using the *.cls files from the "Frontiers in *" Scientific Journals. They have their own classes and templates and examples. I put the *cls files in my `texmf` directory and did the `texhash` and
now they work. But the class has some logo defined and used on the `\maketitle` command. I have the file, but it doesn't work if i put it in the same directory where the class file is.

Should I have a copy of the logo files inside the directory where my work is?
I find that inconvenient.

Comment: Where precisely did you save the files?

Comment: images are searched along the same search path as tex files (including class files) so it should work to put them in any directory where the class file is if the class is found, the image will be.